# How can I initialize a map without explicitly invoking an explicit constructor?

Tags: c++, stdmap, initializer-list

I am trying to initialize a `std::map` with an initializer list (in production, this is a member initializer of a class, but my minimal failing example is below). Given

```
#include <map>

struct Cfg {};

struct Alg
{
    explicit Alg(Cfg const&) {}
};

using MyMap = std::map<int, Alg>;

int main()
{

    Cfg cfg;

    MyMap m = {
        {1, {cfg}},      // error #1
        {2, cfg},        // error #2
        {3, Alg(cfg)},   // works fine
    };

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling, error #1 is:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:22:5: error: converting to ‘const Alg’ from initializer list would use 
explicit constructor ‘Alg::Alg(const Cfg&)’
     };
     ^
```

This is pretty straightforward. Passing a `Cfg` to the initializer requires conversion and the explicit constructor prohibits it.

Error #2 is

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:22:5: error: converting to ‘std::pair<const int, Alg>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&) [with _U1 = int; _U2 = Cfg&; typename std::enable_if<(std::_PCC<true, _T1, _T2>::_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && (! std::_PCC<true, _T1, _T2>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>())), bool>::type <anonymous> = 0; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Alg]’
     };
     ^
```

This is a little more confusing. I think the error talks about implicitly invoking an explicit `std::pair` constructor; reading the documentation for `std::pair`, I get lost in which constructors are explicit when.

The third case is explicit construction. For reasons of maintainability, I'd rather not do that.

It seems like I've read that many initializer list counter-intuitive issues are solvable by adding more braces (gross simplification) but I confess I'm lost at this point.

If I remove the `explicit` qualification of the `Alg` constructor, all three cases compile. However, I'm not sure it makes sense to provide implicit conversion just to simplify an initializer list.

Is there a way to initialize my map elements without explicitly constructing the `Alg` members? Using g++ 7.3

Comment: You provided `explicit`. And you noticed that removing it solves the problem. It seems you want implicit construction enabled, but only when it's convenient for you. You have to choose one or the other. If you want to compiler to only allow implicit construction when you ask it to, it's equivalent to just not having any implicit construction at all. In both case you have to tell the compiler to allow the construction.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough in my head what constitutes implicit construction.     
    `Alg a1(cfg);` and 
    `Alg a2{cfg};` are explicit but 

    `Alg a3 = cfg;` and 
    `Alg a4 = {cfg};` are implicit

Comment: @jwm Implicit construction is when an object of type `Alg` is constructed implicitly from a `cfg`. If you have `f(Alg)` and call `f(cfg)`, then a `Alg` has to be implicitly constructed, which is not allowed if the constructor is explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way around specifying the `Alg` type. This is the intention of `explicit` constructors anyhow. Just for the sake of [I don't know what to say here], you can nevertheless invoke `std::pair`'s in-place constructor like the following.

```
MyMap m{{std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::tie(cfg)}};
```

This way, you don't have to type `Alg`, which kind of answers your questions. Besides, do the above only if you hate yourself and your co-workers.

Note: the in-place constructor of `std::pair` is actually present to allow for non-copyable, non-movable types.